# How to use "Cloud-based maps styling" in lib "@react-google-maps/api"

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a React code with . I created in console.cloud "Map styles" and mapId and linked them. Then I added the mapId to the code, but the styles didn't change.

```
render() {

return (
  <LoadScript
    mapIds={["xxxxxxxxxxxxx"]}
    // id="6e120bcd575d29f7"
    googleMapsApiKey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  >
    <GoogleMap
      mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
      center={{
        lat: 50.751642333131244, 
        lng: 25.329876895818945
      }}
      zoom={17}
    >
           <Marker
            onLoad={this.onLoad}
            position={{
                lat: 50.7516779698738, 
                lng: 25.329030658899786
              }}
            />
    </GoogleMap>
  </LoadScript>
)
```

}
}

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling?hl=en#using_map_ids_in_your_application_code

Answer (score 7):

To implement Cloud-based maps styling, you need to add the mapId in the Maps Javascript script tag's `&map_ids=` parameter and the map object `mapId` parameter. The code you have only adds the mapId in the Maps JavaScript script tag. To add the mapId in your map object parameter, you need to add the `mapId` option inside your  object to implement this styling using the `@react-google-maps/api` library. See [working sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mapid-styling-zmf851?file=Map.js) and code snippet below:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";

import {
  GoogleMap,
  LoadScript
} from "@react-google-maps/api";
const lib = ["places"];
const id = ["6e120bcd575d29f7"]
const key = ""; // PUT GMAP API KEY HERE
const defaultLocation = { lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 };

class Map extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey={key} libraries={lib} mapIds={id} >
        <GoogleMap
          center={defaultLocation}
          zoom={5}
          options={{ mapId: "6e120bcd575d29f7" }}
          mapContainerStyle={{ height: "400px", width: "800px" }}
        />
        </LoadScript>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: **Where** is the fact that you need the `map_ids` parameter in the script tag documented?

Answer (score -1):

I removed **mapId** then styles worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).